# First-time US passport application: will they accept a *certified copy* of my naturalization certificate?

Tags: usa, passports

The state department requires newly naturalized citizens to send in their naturalization certificate along with their first passport application. Several people have told me this *has* to be the original certificate – that it cannot be a copy, and that the original will be sent back to me. Unfortunately, things do get lost in the mail sometimes and replacing the naturalization certificate not only costs hundreds of dollars but also takes at least six months from what I have read. The same people have told me that sending in the original made them nervous, and I do not want to take that risk.

So I'd much rather send a certified copy than the original. On the day of my naturalization, USCIS was kind enough to make a certified copy on the spot. It's a color photocopy with an affixed, signed, and stamped page stating that the photocopy is true. It looks [like this](https://www.nationalapostille.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/USCIS-Form-G-24.jpg). (Only in my case it's not an apostille, ignore the red writing.)

The question is whether the state department will accept the certified copy in lieu of the original. [Here](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/how-apply/citizenship-evidence.html), they say:

> Submit your original evidence of U.S. citizenship. [...] In some cases, you may be able to submit a certified copy of your citizenship evidence. A **certified copy** is any document that has the seal or stamp of the official issuing authority.

As a naturalized citizen, "evidence of U.S. citizenship" is my naturalization certificate. They say "[i]n some cases" but they don't seem to specify on that page. My copy does have the seal they ask for, however.

On the [passport-application form itself](https://eforms.state.gov/Forms/ds11.pdf), section 1 "PROOF OF CITIZENSHIP", they say:

> Submit an original **or certified copy** [of your naturalization certificate] [emphasis mine]

To me that sounds like they should accept my certified copy. Yet everyone I have spoken to who has done their first passport application insists I have to send in the original. Someone even suggested that by "certified copy" the state department means the *replacement* naturalization certificate (the thing that would take six months to get).

All this makes me wonder if there's something I'm not seeing. I think fellow immigrants would be delighted to know if it is true they don't have to part with their naturalization certificate.

Can I send a certified copy of my naturalization certificate or does it have to be the original after all? If your answer is to send the original, how do you square that with the quotes I have provided?

PS: I have seen [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/169645/127204) but it makes no mention of certified copies or the quotes I provided.

Comment: You can just send it, worst case they'll send it back to you and say that you must send an original. However, do you know anyone whose certificate was lost in the mail? And no, replacement certificate is *not* a certified copy, it's a replacement certificate (original).

Comment: DS-11 applications have to be submitted in person. Are you sure you need to send the certificate with the application, rather than just having it available for the person you submit the application with to compare to your photocopy before handing it back to you (like your DL/ID)? The reason I ask is that [USCIS says the US Government, including the DoS for passport applications, will always accept a normal photocopy for their purposes](https://www.uscis.gov/tools/how-do-i-guides/us-citizens/how-do-i-obtain-an-authenticated-copy-of-a-certificate-of-naturalization).

Comment: Naturalization Certificates are US government issued, so the DoS can access USCIS records to determine that the certificate in the photocopy is one that was validly issued. This is unlike birth certificates where the records are held by other levels of government and not so easily accessed by DoS, so verification of the citizenship document needs to rely on an evaluation of the original document (at least initially).

Comment: @littleadv "worst case they'll send it back to you" I suppose. God knows how many months they'd waste doing that. Re lost mail, there's been a problem in my apartment complex with the mailman putting mail in the wrong apartments' mailboxes. I've filed a report with USPS but nothing's changed. Point is: my mail is not reliable enough to entrust with a $500+ document.

Comment: @world-traveler maybe consider a POB address? Although in my experience that was actually worse than trusting my mailman. However, it took about 2 weeks for the DOS to return my docs to me, and they did it with priority mail with tracking number, so not completely untraceable.

Comment: @Dennis "Are you sure you need to send the certificate" Since the form says "submit" for proof of citizenship vs "present" for the ID, I'd guess 'yes'. The link to the USCIS page is very interesting. They contradict themselves; at the oath ceremony they were adamant we'd all have to send in the original. The passport form they gave us was version 06-2016 which indeed makes no mention of certified copies. But the one from 12-2020 does. Maybe the DoS just put naturalization certificates in the same category as birth certificates and didn't bother to say it doesn't have to be an original.